# How can I change the url or site name when requesting to access audio stream using MediaDevices.getUserMedia in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediadevices

We have a Chrome Extension that requests permission to access the user's audio stream to allow them to record while navigating the web. The issue we are facing is that the popup request displays the url of the page that the user is on and not our product url or extension name and could be misleading to the user.

Ex. if we are on stackoverflow.com and the extension is enabled the permission to access the user's audio stream states that stackoverflow.com is requesting to access the audio stream rather than our url

Is there a way to control the url or name in the request for permissions?

Comment: Maybe tell the user in advance that they will be prompted, this way they won't be confused